# Python clash of clans bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I am a beginner in programming and wanted to automate the process of searching for an enemy in clash of clans. I want the bot to search for an enemy with recourses of 700 000 of each. When the bot finds the enemy I want it to make a sound. This is what I currently have:

```
import pyautogui
import time
# ingame recourses 
gold = input(Image)
elexir = input(Image)
dark_elexir input(Image)

# if enemy is found then play sound 
if elexir > 700000:
    play(sound)
    if gold > 700000:
        play(sound)
        if dark_elexir > 2000:
            play(sound)

# if not then skip and go on searching                       
else:
    pyautogui.leftClick(1642, 773, duration=5)
   

time.sleep(3)
#pyautogui.moveTo(<->, up )

# this goes the attack button 
pyautogui.leftClick(200, 920, duration=0.5)
pyautogui.leftClick(1480, 703, duration=1)

# this presses the skip button 
pyautogui.leftClick(1642, 773, duration=5)
pyautogui.leftClick(1642, 773, duration=5)
pyautogui.leftClick(1642, 773, duration=5)
```

I don't know how to make python see my screen and I cant find a tutorial on that.

Comment: Have you tried using `locateonscreen()` method?

Comment: @pptx704 no I haven't, I will try